# function not running properly? (Tank Auth)

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, tankauth

Could someone please explain why there is a difference between

```
function foo($a){$blah = $a}.......
foo($CONSTANT);
```

and

```
function foo() { $blah = $CONSTANT}.......
foo();
```

The top method is working for me, the other is not. 
Specifically the below finds the if statement false:

```
$this->setsession($user->id,$user->email, ($user->activated == 1) ? STATUS_ACTIVATED : STATUS_NOT_ACTIVATED);

                        if ($user->activated == 0) {                            // fail - not activated
                            $this->error = array('not_activated' => '');
```

While this one finds it true:

```
$this->setsession();

                        if ($user->activated == 0) {                            // fail - not activated
                            $this->error = array('not_activated' => '');
```

Comment: Your code snippets don't make sense. Both have the same identical second and third lines. Unless you're modifying the value of `$user->activated` inside `setSession()` the code shouldn't fail. Could you clean up the code?

Comment: Sorry for the poor wording, I couldn't figure out a way to explain it really since I didn't even know what the problem was. I fixed my actual code, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for a poorly written question.
The difference is variable scope, I need to pass the variables because the ones I was calling were not able to be referenced.